# Why does AND(TRUE, <thing>) sometimes change the value of <thing>?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following formula in Excel that finds duplicate entries in a list. For some reason, surrounding COUNTIF with the AND(TRUE, ...) doesn't filter any cells. Why could this happen?

```
=FILTER('BTC list'!A2:A2000, AND(TRUE, COUNTIF('BTC list'!A2:A2000, 'BTC list'!A2:A2000) > 1), "")
```

EDIT: to clarify, with the AND(TRUE part, the formula works as intended.

EDIT 2: I think it has something to do with the filter. Is there a better way to refer to the current cell being analyzed for the filter instead of just putting in the range? i.e. the second argument of COUNTIF is supposed to be the current cell being analyzed.

Comment: I've circumvented this issue. Still curious though if anyone knows why this happens.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. (1) A new reader doesn't care of previous versions; what matters is if the current version of the question is coherent, on-topic and [generally good](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). And we have the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1723987/revisions). For these reasons usually there is no need to litter the question with "EDIT" or so. (2) I think an [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659) will be useful (with screenshots if needed). Let us duplicate one exact example of the problem on our computers.

Comment: `countif` returns a number, it looks like you are thinking it returns the range of items that match your criteria...

Comment: COUTIF problem..can you provide a sample about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

AND is not a row-wise expression. Your AND function will return exactly one value - either TRUE or FALSE. The filter condition in the FILTER function must be an array the same size as the array being filtered.

[image]

If you want to return the rows that have duplicates, just do this:

```
=LET(d,$A$2:$A$21,FILTER(d,COUNTIF(d,d)>1))
```

[image]